# Read .smi files without tags

Tags: subtitles

When I read .smi files on ordinary text editors, they come with many tags.
But I can read this without tags using Internet Explorer, I think.
How can do this on Mac?
I tried Safari, Chrome and Firefox but all failed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the .SMI you have is a [Synchronized Accessible Media Interchange (SAMI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMI) file or a [Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language (SMIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language) file. The latter is used by [RealPlayer](http://service.real.com/help/library/guides/realone/ProductionGuide/HTML/htmfiles/smilintr.htm) especially and is an XML-based format, whereas the former is an HTML+CSS based format.

Regardless, if IE is hiding the tags then that's a result of how its parser and [layout engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) are dealing with the format, and it's unlikely you can replicate this on a Mac. If you're editing the files then a good text editor would be recommended anyway, and hiding the tags makes no sense. If you want to view the files, instead of doing so separately use a media player that'll display them along with their associated videos.